I don't understand how to add my extension locally correctly
I want to use the Draw Tool Extension. In my Autodesk Forge Viewer. When I download the extension like this, it works. https://github.getafreenode.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-extensions/blob/main/public/extensions/DrawToolExtension
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/autodesk-forge/forge-extensions/public/extensions/DrawToolExtension/contents/main.css"> 
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/autodesk-forge/forge-extensions/public/extensions/DrawToolExtension/contents/main.js"></script> 

But I would like to change the extension code for my needs. I specify it locally
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

But it stops working, and I don't understand why

Have you copied the main.js and main.css into the same folder as the html snippet?

check on developer tools (F11 on windows, cmd option i on mac), probably you are having CORS policy issue.

If you are copying the extension files to your own application, please make sure that their path is setup correctly. For example, in the snippet you shared:
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

the two files are expected to be located in the same folder as the HTML file where these <script> and <link> tags are used.
We usually recommend storing the extension assets in a subfolder, let's say like this:
- your-project-folder/
  - wwwroot/
    - your-custom-extension/
      - main.js
      - main.css
    - index.html
    - index.js
    - index.css

In this case the <script> and <link> tags in the index.html file should look like this:
<script type="text/javascript" src="./your-custom-extension/main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./your-custom-extension/main.css">

Also, make sure that the main.js file is included after the viewer3D.min.js file.
